# Prevent conda from changing CFLAGS / CPPFLAGS

Tags: conda

When I activate a conda environment it seems to set CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS. Of particular annoyance is the fact that it sets optimization level `-O2`, which in many cases interferes with the ability to create non-optimized debug builds.

Is there a way to prevent conda from setting these variables in the first place?

Comment: This behavior is typically tied to having [a `compilers`-like package](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#dep-compilers) installed, which brings in activation scripts through support packages (e.g., [`ctng-compiler-activation`](https://github.com/conda-forge/ctng-compiler-activation-feedstock/tree/main/recipe)). That is, "conda" doesn't do this, but specific packages do, so a clear answer is not possible without more context about the activated environment.

Comment: But I would expect that these scripts support a debug mode - e.g., they have things like `DEBUG_CXXFLAGS` in them. Maybe ask on the Conda Forge Gitter, since the Core team likely knows how to toggle such this.

Comment: Thanks for the context @merv - you are correct seems like this only happens in environments where a compiler is installed

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to install compilers in Conda environments is through metapackages, like what Conda Forge provides with `compilers` or `cxx-compiler`. These install not only a compiler, but a bunch of supporting packages that simplify the typical way a Conda user might do compilation. This includes setting up lots of environment variables, like `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS`, etc.. Moreover, this automates connecting how Conda provides libraries and headers to the compiler being used.

However, Conda Forge has all this stuff modularized. So if you don't want all those connections established for you in the background, but instead want an unconfigured compiler, that's also possible.  For example, on **osx-64**, a `c-compiler` package would install `clang`, plus a bunch of auxiliary packages. But if instead you just install `clang` directly, then you'll get only the compiler, and activating the environment won’t trigger any such environment variables to be set.